# Does Django makes additional query on accessing prefetched M2M field through "values()" or "values_list()"?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.0

*models.py*:

```py
class DemoA(models.Model):
    M = < M2M-Field to DemoB>

class DemoB(models.Model):
    title = < CharField >
```

---

**Queryset** with prefetch:

```py
qs = DemoA.objects.all().prefetch_related('M')
```

`prefetch_related` works good when used with `.all()` as stated in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

*Eg:*

```py
# This is the expected use case and will not make any additional query
for row in qs:
    print(row.M.all())
```

---

#### 1) Now what if I try to access it using `.values()` or `.values_list()` methods ? Will it make additional query(s) ?

*Eg:*

```py
print(qs.values('M'))

# OR

print(qs.values_list('M'))
```

---

#### 2) Additional:

What if I access the property of `M` in a similar way? Will it make any additional query?

*Eg:*

```py
print(qs.values('M__title'))
```

---

If it does make query(s) in both the cases, what is the perfect way to do the same? Is it good to loop over all and extract their properties?

Comment: If you have questions about what queries are being ran your best option is to use the debug toolbar: https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/  The toolbar has a SQL view that shows you the raw SQL being executed as well as how long the SQL calls are taking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes. It will make additional query.**

#### Reason:

The "prefetched" queryset is of DemoB model class. When accessing through `row.M.all()`, the queryset which is used is of DemoB model class, and the query remains the same. Whereas in case of `print(qs.values('M'))` the queryset which is used if of DemoA model class, and hence the built query is different.

And as per the docs:

> Remember that, as always with QuerySets, any subsequent chained methods which imply a different database query will ignore previously cached results, and retrieve data using a fresh database query.